# Failing to install Nokogiri on Mac Catalina

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to set up my local environment and install nokogiri but am getting this error (apologies for the length):

```
 ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
/Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200716-95822-kw9idg.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts  -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.4.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.10
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch
    - 0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch
    - 0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch
    - 0004-libxml2.la-is-in-top_builddir.patch
    - 0005-Fix-infinite-loop-in-xmlStringLenDecodeEntities.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.10.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.10... OK
Running git apply with /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0004-libxml2.la-is-in-top_builddir.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0005-Fix-infinite-loop-in-xmlStringLenDecodeEntities.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.10 (from /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/libxml2/2.9.10)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.34.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.34.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.34... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.34 (from /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/libxslt/1.1.34)...
checking for -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling html_document.c
html_document.c:16:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "0*", &rest);
                           ^
1 warning generated.
compiling html_element_description.c
compiling html_entity_lookup.c
compiling html_sax_parser_context.c
compiling html_sax_push_parser.c
compiling nokogiri.c
compiling xml_attr.c
xml_attr.c:61:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &document, &name, &rest);
                           ^
1 warning generated.
compiling xml_attribute_decl.c
compiling xml_cdata.c
xml_cdata.c:23:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &doc, &content, &rest);
                           ^
xml_cdata.c:29:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    content_str_len = RSTRING_LEN(content);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1000:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:996:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_cdata.c:29:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    content_str_len = RSTRING_LEN(content);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1001:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling xml_comment.c
xml_comment.c:21:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &document, &content, &rest);
                           ^
1 warning generated.
compiling xml_document.c
xml_document.c:330:31: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  if(rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &level) == 0)
                              ^
xml_document.c:357:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "0*", &rest);
                           ^
xml_document.c:436:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "14", &name, &type, &external_id, &system_id,
                           ^
xml_document.c:511:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "03", &mode, &incl_ns, &with_comments);
                           ^
4 warnings generated.
compiling xml_document_fragment.c
xml_document_fragment.c:17:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "1*", &document, &rest);
                           ^
1 warning generated.
compiling xml_dtd.c
compiling xml_element_content.c
compiling xml_element_decl.c
compiling xml_encoding_handler.c
compiling xml_entity_decl.c
compiling xml_entity_reference.c
xml_entity_reference.c:18:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &document, &name, &rest);
                           ^
1 warning generated.
compiling xml_io.c
compiling xml_libxml2_hacks.c
compiling xml_namespace.c
compiling xml_node.c
xml_node.c:304:15: warning: passing 'const xmlChar *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      xmlFree(reparentee->ns->prefix);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_node.c:550:37: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  n_args = rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "02", &r_level, &r_new_parent_doc);
                                    ^
xml_node.c:1393:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &name, &document, &rest);
                           ^
3 warnings generated.
compiling xml_node_set.c
xml_node_set.c:294:30: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "11", NULL, NULL);
                             ^
1 warning generated.
compiling xml_processing_instruction.c
xml_processing_instruction.c:20:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "3*", &document, &name, &content, &rest);
                           ^
1 warning generated.
compiling xml_reader.c
xml_reader.c:533:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "13", &rb_buffer, &rb_url, &encoding, &rb_options);
                           ^
xml_reader.c:577:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "13", &rb_io, &rb_url, &encoding, &rb_options);
                           ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling xml_relax_ng.c
compiling xml_sax_parser.c
compiling xml_sax_parser_context.c
compiling xml_sax_push_parser.c
compiling xml_schema.c
compiling xml_syntax_error.c
compiling xml_text.c
xml_text.c:18:28: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &string, &document, &rest);
                           ^
1 warning generated.
compiling xml_xpath_context.c
xml_xpath_context.c:200:31: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
  if(rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "11", &search_path, &xpath_handler) == 1)
                              ^
1 warning generated.
compiling xslt_stylesheet.c
xslt_stylesheet.c:141:30: warning: cast from 'const char *' to 'char *' drops const qualifier [-Wcast-qual]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "11", &xmldoc, &paramobj);
                             ^
xslt_stylesheet.c:112:13: warning: unused function 'swallow_superfluous_xml_errors' [-Wunused-function]
static void swallow_superfluous_xml_errors(void * userdata, xmlErrorPtr error, ...)
            ^
2 warnings generated.
linking shared-object nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib'
Cleaning files only used during build.
rm -rf /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/ports
rm -rf /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ports

current directory: /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: *** [.sitearchdir.-.nokogiri.time] Error 1

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/michaelnavoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.10.10/gem_make.out
```

I have tried several of the fixes offered to others having issues installing nokogiri including:

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
xcode-select --install
gem install nokogiri
```

and

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/
```

which seem to fix the issue for most users. I have also looked through the docs on https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html regarding Mac installation to no avail. This issue needs to be resolved before I am able to install the rails gem as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thoughts?

Using Catalina 10.15.5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using **homebrew** on a google translated Japanese page:
https://qiita.com/takeru56/items/9dc2b2aec56aaed69740

Download and install **homebrew**:
https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Then install **coreutils**:

```
$ brew install coreutils

==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/coreutils-8.32.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/67a4452d75a1882bd7fb977b384204edfa2758276d66290e595487922368e
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring coreutils-8.32.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Commands also provided by macOS have been installed with the prefix "g".
If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
  PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.32: 476 files, 9.2MB
```

Then I successfully installed nokogiri:

```
$ gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.10.10
1 gem installed
```